# Trouble using BEM with SASS

Tags: sass, gulp, bem

I am trying to integrate BEM into my sass.  I am also using Gulp.  When I don't use BEM my code works fine.  When I include BEM, the code no longer works.

Here is my HTML with out BEM.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="stage">
      <li class="scene">
        <div class="movie">
          <div class="poster"></div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my SASS

```
.wrapper{
  margin: 100px auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  .stage{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    .scene {
      width: 260px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 30px;
      float: left;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML using BEM

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="stage">
          <li class="stage__scene">
            <div class="movie">
              <div class="poster"></div>
             </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is my SASS with BEM

```
.wrapper{
  margin: 100px auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  .stage{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    &__scene {
      width: 260px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 30px;
      float: left;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to BEM so I am pretty sure I am missing something obvious.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure what "no longer works". But your CSS / SASS code doesn't conform to BEM. BEM deliberately limits the use of cascading. Because blocks are independent, a block (`.stage`) shouldn't be styled as a descendant of another block (`.wrapper`).

Here is a BEM-compliant SASS code:

```
.wrapper{
  margin: 100px auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}
.stage{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  &__scene {
    width: 260px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 30px;
    float: left;
    perspective: 1000px;
  }
}
```

See also: [the official BEM methodology](https://en.bem.info/methodology/quick-start/).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a BEM issue, but an "issue" with SASS compiler. I don't know that you can do class concatenation like that. The way you have the sass written is looking for a div with 2 separate classes, `stage` and `__scene` on the same element, not a single class called `stage__scene` on a nested element.

Your sass should look like this:

```
.wrapper{
  margin: 100px auto;
  max-width: 960px;
  .stage{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    .stage__scene {
      width: 260px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 30px;
      float: left;
      perspective: 1000px;
    }
  }
}
```